# html2canvas mobile view set specific size when converting to image for download

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html2canvas

After literary whole day and a half I finally find a way to convert my dynamically produced "paper" (like invoice) for download that works in ALL browsers. (Chrome is giant pain in the ***).

Currently  I'm using html2canvas.js and converting canvas to image and forcing browsers to download it:

```
html2canvas($('#printableArea')[0], {
scale:0.8
}).then(function(canvas) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  a.download = 'nalog.png';
  a.click();
});
```

And only one more little step to restore faith in humanity is left. On normal screen sizes div is set to max width 900px, and that works. BUT when on mobile view div that canvas is made of is of coarse very long, and I don't care about that it is responsive as it should be. BUT it image made out of it is also.
Normal image and mobile:

[image]      [image]

I understand that canvas is made out of my current screen size.
But Is it possible to set the size of canvas or div dynamically inside my code so that it produces normal size even on mobile view?

EDIT:

As this questions is getting some views, I urge you to give up on this approach and generate PDF's server side where screen sizes wont matter.

Comment: is there a solution now?

Comment: @Amal yes. never use front-end document rendering, use server-side...

Comment: sorry, I don't get it

Comment: generate your documents on a server with something else, not with JS in the front end. @Amal